# Admin page access using IP address

Tags: php, pdo, xampp

I have created an admin page with name admin.php. But I want it to be accessed when I enter an IP address in format say XXX.XXX.X.X in the address bar. Please, can anyone help on how do I do that? I am using pdo php on XAMPP on mac yosemite.

Comment: Well, basically you need an http server and the correct routing so that a request of a browser using that ip address gets sent to that http server. This is well documented. You should start by reading a few "getting started guides".

Comment: Thank you but what concept do I need to refer. And which getting started guides do I have to refer????

Comment: What do you mean by "concept"? About the guides: you do know how to google for information I assume? Did you try? Start here maybe: http://php.net/manual/en/getting-started.php

Comment: @nevermind What "text field"? The OP is referring to the browsers address bar as I understand it.

Comment: Yeah arkascha . Thank You .

Comment: To be clear, I jus need to open my admin page through IP address in the browser and not by typing the filename.

Comment: Ah, ok, that is more clear. In that case you have to change in the IndexDocument setting inside your http servers configuration to point to that file name. Or you add a request router which calls that admin page when the normal index document is accessed.

Comment: Okie. That wil be helpful . I'll try tht.

Comment: You are welcome. Again: consult the documentation. That is what it has been written for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you're on a Mac: things are easier than on Windows.

All you have to do is to open the "terminal" application and to type the command `ifconfig` (and, of course, ENTER).

In the result, pretty similar to the screenshot above, you'll see a line like

```
 inet 10.1.1.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.1.1.255
```

telling you the IP address of your network card.

BTW, validation based on IPs is not a Good Thing, because IPs can be "spoofed", as explained here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address_spoofing

Comment: Yep ,M on mac. Thank You for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> But I want it to be accessed when I enter an IP address in format say
>   XXX.XXX.X.X in the address bar

1. Assuming your XAMPP Apache runs on PORT **80** (Default)
2. Assuming you are on Windows 7

Go to your Command prompt

- Click on windows logo (left-bottom)
- Type `cmd`
- click on cmd.exe icon

[image]

- When you see a black window
- Type `ipconfig` [ENTER]
- Search for IPv4 Address

[image]

- Use that IP in you browser like this (your IP might be different)

[image]

If you access from the same computer you can use **127.0.0.1** or **localhost**

**There is one little catch Windows Firewall**

You can configure it following this:

Go to Control panel - > go to Windows Firewall -> then Advance Settings ->

- Click Inbound Rules
- Right Click the inbound rules and select "New Rule..."
- Select option port and click next
- Select all local ports or your port number for apache server. and click next
- Select option allow the connection and click next
- Next
- Give name Allow All Local Port For Xampp

**Or you can disable (temporally - no recommended but easier)**

Go to Control panel - > go to Windows Firewall -> then Advance Settings ->

Turn off public and work networks